# r ggplot geom_bar allow bar maximum to be greater than ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data where the relevant substantive range is 0 to 1. I get some results that well over 1; 3-6. When this happens geom_bar sets the values to NA.

I want to set the maximum y value to say 1.5, and when the data value is greater than 1.5, the bar is cut off at the top.

Here's some code to demonstrate. With yRange <- c(0,2), R returns

> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).

and plots the two bars with 1 and 2 as values.

```
dt <- data.table(scenario = c("Scen1", "Scen2", "Scen3", "Scen4"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
yRange <- c(0,2)
p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = scenario, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Y label", limits = yRange)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use coord_cartesian instead of scale_y_continuous, as in the following code. And I have added a text label to the bar so that it is clearer that the bar extends beyond the top of the plot. Other improvements would be to use color to highlight the bar values.

```
dt <- data.table(scenario = c("Scen1", "Scen2", "Scen3", "Scen4"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
yRange <- c(0,2)
p <- ggplot(dt, aes(x = scenario, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian( ylim = yRange) +
  geom_text(aes(x=scenario,y=value,label=value),position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
print(p)
```